# Limit point of sequence and set

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that set $1-\frac{1}{2^{n}} $ $\cup$ {1} is closed Set.  So I know that if I can show $1-\frac{1}{2^{n}} $ has limit point $1$ only. So We are done. How to do that ? I know that if I take neighbourhood around $1$ then it contains infinitly many points in given set and hence it is limit point ; but how to write formally ?

Comment: "if I take neighbourhood around 1 then it contains infinitly many points in given set and hence it is limit point" is pretty close to writing it formally. Some minor rephrasing to disambiguate is the only thing you need to do. Of course, you could also expand on _why_ that statement is true. There is also a bit of work remaining to show there are no _other_ limit points.

Comment: @Fred how to show  1 is only limit point ?

Comment: @Arthur How to show 1 is only limit point ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $ \epsilon >0$ and consider the intervall $U:=(1-\epsilon,1+ \epsilon).$ Since $1- \frac{1}{2^n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty,$ there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$$|(1-\frac{1}{2^n})-1| < \epsilon$$

for $n>N.$ This means

$$1- \frac{1}{2^n} \in U$$

for $n >N.$

Comment: why $\left|1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right|<\epsilon$ this is true ?

Comment: Ooops... I mean $|(1-\frac{1}{2^n})-1| < \epsilon$.

Comment: How to show that this is only limit point ?